# HTML background color issue with fill in

Tags: html, background-color

My question concerns the background color of the 'DETAILS' button. The problem I came across is that not all of the button area is filled in with color. [button pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sWMt.png)

```
<div className={classes.DetailsBtn}>
    <a href="">
       Details
    </a>
</div>
```

```
.DetailsBtn {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(3, 37, 65, 0.25);
}

.DetailsBtn a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #032541;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.DetailsBtn a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #032541;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey line around the button is being caused due to the 'border' setting in the css.

It can be removed by making these changes:

1. Remove border from the 'div' level (**.DetailsBtn**)
2. Add border to **'.DetailsBtn a'**
3. Add border to **'.DetailsBtn a:hover'**

**Working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button colour</title>
        <style>
            .DetailsBtn {
                flex: 0 0 10%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .DetailsBtn a {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                line-height: 26px;
                text-decoration: none;
                background: #032541;
                color: #fff;
                transition: all 0.5s;
                border: 1px solid rgba(3, 37, 65, 0.25);
            }
            .DetailsBtn a:hover {
                background: #fff;
                color: #032541;
                border: 1px solid rgba(3, 37, 65, 0.25);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="DetailsBtn" style="width:200px;">
            <a href="#">
               Details
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, that really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line of code

```
.DetailsBtn {
flex: 0 0 10%;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid rgba(3, 37, 65, 0.25);  <-- remove this line!
}
```